# titanium listView dynamic data binding

Tags: listview, data-binding, titanium-alloy

`sdk: 3.5.1`

I'm not familiar with `listView` mechanics. I'm trying to understand how to apply JSON data values to the item template's bound properties.

I start with mapping the data

```
//example 
var data = ({data:json-data, index:'label'});

var _data = _.map(data, function(item, index) {
    return {
        properties: {
            categoryLabel: index,
            data: item

        }
    }
});
```

I then want to bind it to my list

`$.activityDetailsList.sections[0].setItems(_data);`

In my view I have

```
<ListView defaultItemTemplate="activityDetailsListItemTemplate" id="activityDetailsList">
  <Templates>
    <ItemTemplate name="activityDetailsListItemTemplate">
      <Label bindId="categoryLabel" class="rowTitle" id="categoryLabel"/>
      <View bindId="rightSpacer" id="rightSpacer">
        <ImageView bindId="arrowImage" id="arrowImage"/>
      </View>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </Templates>
 <ListSection id="activityDetailsListSection">
    <ListItem template='activityDetailsListItemTemplate'/>
  </ListSection>
</ListView>
```

When I iterate through five elements, all I get back are blank rows with the corresponding arrows.

[image]

Here's my question: How do I get the `categoryLabel` text values to display? Do I have to define it in the template? This part isn't clear to me. I thought simply binding the data to the template was enough. Apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me:

view xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <ListView defaultItemTemplate="dailyActivitiesTemplate" id="activityList" top="30">
            <Templates>
                <ItemTemplate name="dailyActivitiesTemplate">
                    <View id="dailyActivities">
                        <View class="row" id="fundRow">
                            <Label class="rowTitle" id="fund" text="Fund: "/>
                            <Label bindId="fund" class="rowValue" id="fund"/>
                        </View>
                        <View class="row" id="amountRow">
                            <Label class="rowTitle" id="amount" text="Amount: "/>
                            <Label bindId="amount" class="rowValue" id="amount"/>
                        </View>
                        <View class="row" id="unitsRow">
                            <Label class="rowTitle" id="units" text="Units: "/>
                            <Label bindId="units" class="rowValue" id="units"/>
                        </View>
                        <View class="row" id="sourceRow">
                            <Label class="rowTitle" id="source" text="Source: "/>
                            <Label bindId="source" class="rowValue" id="source"/>
                        </View>
                        <View class="row" id="unitValueRow">
                            <Label class="rowTitle" id="unitValue" text="Unit Value: "/>
                            <Label bindId="unitValue" class="rowValue" id="unitValue"/>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </Templates>
            <ListSection>
                <ListItem template="dailyActivitiesTemplate"/>
            </ListSection>
        </ListView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

controller:

```
var items = [];

_.map(_.first(activities), function(element, key) {

    if (moment(new Date(key)).isValid()) {

        _.each(element, function(item, key) {
            items.push({
                fund: {
                    text: item.fund
                },
                amount: {
                    text: item.amount
                },
                units: {
                    text: item.units
                },
                source: {
                    text: item.source
                },
                unitValue: {
                    text: item.unitValue
                }
            });

        });
    }

});
$.activityList.sections[0].setItems(items);
```

The important point for me is that I didn't need the `properties:{}` parent. That confused me. Now that I had data in the view, I just needed to style it with the TSS file.